# Match a line, append those under it

Tags: python, regex, loops

I'm trying to edit the format of a file, right no it looks like this:

> > >Cluster 0
> >     L07510
> >     >Cluster 1
> >     AF480591
> >     AY457083
> >     >Cluster 2
> >     M88154
> >     >Cluster 3
> >     CP000924
> >     L09161
> >     >Cluster 4
> >     AY742307
> >     >Cluster 5
> >     L09163
> >     L09162
> >     >Cluster 6
> >     AF321086
> >     >Cluster 7
> >     DQ666175
> >     >Cluster 8
> >     DQ288691

I want to write something in python that will go trough each line, stop at the lines that say ">Cluster x" (x being a number), and then add that number to any lines that follow it. Then when a new ">Cluster x" is reached, it starts again with the new x value.

So it would look like this:

> > >Cluster 0
> >     0 L07510
> >     >Cluster 1
> >     1 AF480591
> >     1 AY457083
> >     >Cluster 2
> >     2 M88154
> >     >Cluster 3
> >     3 CP000924
> >     3 L09161
> >     >Cluster 4
> >     4 AY742307
> >     >Cluster 5
> >     5 L09163
> >     5 L09162
> >     >Cluster 6
> >     6 AF321086
> >     >Cluster 7
> >     7 DQ666175
> >     >Cluster 8
> >     8 DQ288691

I was thinking I could use a `regex`, searching for `">Cluster x"` (would the regex look like this? `('\>Cluster \d+')`) and then have the program append each line following this matched regex with whatever `\d+` is. I'm just not sure how to actually write this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why python?  This problem seems like a good fit for awk.

Comment: You can use parentheses `(\d+)` to capture the digits, and then get that by using the `group` method on the `Match` object returned by `re.match`

Comment: I'm trying to learn python right now, so I'm trying to do all my work with it

Comment: One liner, even: `awk '/>Cluster/ { val = $2; print; next } { print val, $0 }' file`

Comment: As a general rule, don't resort to `regex` if a simpler method will work. This will save you a lot of grief in the long run.

Comment: @AirThomas I know this is marked as solved, but I'm just curious about not resorting to `regex`, how does it cause grief? I'll avoid it!

Comment: @Jen Sometimes, nothing but a regular expression can reasonably do what you want to do. But regular expressions can quickly become complex enough that it takes way more effort to maintain/troubleshoot them than it would have taken to use a slightly less powerful tool in the first place. "This tool is incredibly powerful, therefore I will use it for _everything I possibly can_," is probably not the best approach. Search on "when not to use regular expressions" for more detail and eloquence than I can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested

```
# If you're on a POSIX compliant system, and this script is marked as 
# executable, the following line will make this file be automatically 
# run by the Python interpreter rather than interpreted as a shell script
#!/usr/bin/env python

# We need the sys module to read arguments from the terminal
import sys

# Open the input file, default mode is 'r', readonly, which is a safe default
infile = open(sys.argv[1])

# Prepare a variable for the cluster number to be used within the loop
cluster = ''

# loop through all lines in the file, but first set up a list comprehension
# that strips the newline character off the line for each line that is read
for line in (line.strip() for line in infile):
    if line.startswith('>'):
        # string.split() splits on whitespace by default
        # we want the cluster number at index 1
        cluster = line.split()[1]

        # output this line to stdout unmodified
        print line

    else:
        # output any other line modified by adding the cluster number
        print cluster + ' ' + line
```

Usage

```
$ python cluster_format.py input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Eureka! I made f = my input file, then used `cat` to dump it into a new file. Thank you!

Comment: Would you be willing to add comments to show me why/how you wrote the above code?

Answer (score 1):

Ooh, I love parsing.

Here's the deal:

```
current_cluster = ""
new_lines = ""

# assuming all this text is in a variable called lines
for line in lines.split("\n"):
    if line.startswith(">Cluster"):
        # 9 characters is ">Cluster "
        current_cluster=line[9:].strip()
    else:
        # otherwise, just take the line itself and prepend the current cluster
        line = "{} {}".format(current_cluster, line)

    new_lines += "{}\n".format(line)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad you love parsing! :D How could I add to this so that it opens a file, does this to the file, then saves as a new name? And how can I learn more about parsing!

Comment: To learn more about parsing, I suggest looking through a lot of data sources and seeing if you can find ways to manipulate the data inside them (usually text files) to get out exactly what you want. Practice is a huge help.